# Spring Webscoket error javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error in nginx

Tags: spring, nginx, spring-websocket, stomp

I using spring-boot-starter-websocket and run localhost is success. But i run in server with Nginx, Spring Gateway is not connected.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat/").setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy()));
  }

}
```

config:

- Nginx port 80
- gateway-service port 8000
- message-service port 8540

client-> Nginx -> gateway-service -> message-service

Run localhost: ws://127.0.0.1:8540/chat/ is ok
Run server: ws://mydomain.xyz/message-service/chat/ error javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake

```
Zull:

server:
  port: 8000

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service

zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 20000
    socket-timeout-millis: 20000
  routes:
    profile-service:
        path: /profile-service/**
        serviceId: profile-service
        stripPrefix: true
    message-service:
        path: /message-service/**
        serviceId: message-service
        stripPrefix: true
```

Error:

```
run:
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
false
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$1.run(ClientManager.java:446)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:620)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:351)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:241)
    at sk.Main.setConnectWebsocket(Main.java:28)
    at sk.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 400
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.Handshake.validateServerResponse(Handshake.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleHandshake(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:547)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: So your "127.0.0.1:8540/chat/" is same as "mydomain.xyz/message-service/chat/"  shouldnt it be "mydomain.xyz/chat/" .

Comment: i using Zull and "message-service" will call to service port 8540